# Integer null in order to check a Data Base

Tags: java, android, database

I've for instance this simple constructor:

```
public Car(String brand, String model, int price){
        this.brand=brand;
        this.model=model;
        this.price=price;
    }
```

So, I need create Objects to check a data base:

```
new Car (null, null, 15000);
new Car (Opel, null, null);
```

I don't have problems in the firs case, but in the second case, the value null for an integer is not allowed.

Any suggestion?

Thank's!

Comment: what do you mean by "check a database" ? Which database system are you using? `int` is a primitive type which cannot be null. Use the `Integer` class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You some default value, like -1, to represent null, or use `Integer`, which can be null, instead of `int`.

Comment: Thank you! Instead of int i've used Integer and works properly

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a primitive value type - there's no such concept as a null value for int.
Therefore you can not assign null to `int`. 
Try to set a default value like -1.
You can use null with `Integer` because that's a class instead of a primitive value.